# Page Sequencing in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to build a segment for users who hit page /company first. This cannot be their only page in the visit.

```
SELECT totals.pageviews, visitid, COUNT(distinct visitorid) as TotalUsers
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([1234567.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2015-01-05'),TIMESTAMP('2015-01-11')))
WHERE hits.hitnumber = 1
   AND page.pageTitle = 'Company Page'
GROUP EACH BY visitorid, visitid
LIMIT 10;
```

This isn't right because this just matches visitors with 1 total hit for their session. I want to specify that hit #1 should equal 'Company Page'.

Is it possible to also create a sequence of pages? For example: a segment that hit Page x, Page y, Page Z - in that specific order.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you could get what you want by querying on the **fullvisitorid** (be careful ***visitorid*** [is deprecated](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en)) and the first page as your company page.

Then just make a query on those visitors whose id is in that subset.

Something like:

```
SELECT fullvisitorid, hits.page.pageTitle 
FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] 
HAVING fullvisitorid IN
(SELECT fullvisitorid
FROM [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] 
WHERE hits.hitnumber = 1 AND hits.page.pageTitle = 'London Cycle Helmet')
LIMIT 1000
```

Where I used the BigQuery public sample of GA (google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet) and 'London Cycle Helmet' as the first page.